# Websocket Handshake failure

Tags: websocket, lua

From a Ubuntu1604 client, I get this error connecting to my server

> Could not connect websocket ws://url err Websocket Handshake failed: Invalid Sec-Websocket-Accept
>   (expected W2+GvfwqcjuEddB+7s+0XX2qJSo= got nil)

I don't see this error from a RHEL7.5 client. So, I dont think its a server issue. What am I missing on the Ubuntu?

Comment: How is this Lua-related?

Comment: This was from a lua client. I did realize that the problem is not seen outside of a corporate network. It seems that a webproxy was causing this issue.